# How to parameterise cluster type (basic/standard/dedicated) on confluent cloud

Tags: terraform, confluent-cloud

I am trying to automate cluster creation process of confluent cloud using terraform. I would like to spawn different clusters for each environment using the same code through parameters.

```
 resource "confluent_kafka_cluster" "standard" {
  display_name = "standard_kafka_cluster"
  availability = "SINGLE_ZONE"
  cloud        = "AZURE"
  region       = "centralus"
  standard {}

  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.development.id
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I would like to parametrize `standard/basic/dedicated` so that I can have basic in dev/staging and standard/dedicated on uat/prod.

I have tried to do it using dynamic block. Haven't got any success yet. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic blocks and `for_each`. However, it seems a bit like tricking Terraform.

```
resource "confluent_kafka_cluster" "example" {
  display_name = var.display_name
  availability = var.availability
  cloud        = var.cloud
  region       = var.region

  dynamic "basic" {
    for_each = [for value in [var.cluster_type] : value if value == "BASIC"]
    content {
    }
  }

  dynamic "standard" {
    for_each = [for value in [var.cluster_type] : value if value == "STANDARD"]
    content {
    }
  }

  dynamic "dedicated" {
    for_each = [for value in [var.cluster_type] : value if value == "DEDICATED"]
    content {
      cku = var.cku
    }
  }

  environment {
    id = var.environment_id
  }

  dynamic "network" {
    for_each = [for value in [var.network_id] : value if value != null]
    content {
      id = network.value
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The resource name cannot be dynamic; that needs to be saved in the state file as a static resource ID.

You could create a Terraform Module, to define a generic `"azure-centralus-confluentcloud"` module, then parameterize the rest, or you can use a [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) to loop over each environment, then use accessors like `confluent_kafka_cluster.clusters["dev"]` when you need a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

**The simple way I achieved it using count**

```
resource "confluent_kafka_cluster" "basic" {
  count        = var.confluent_cluster_type == "basic" ? 1 : 0
  display_name = var.cluster_name
  availability = var.availability
  cloud        = var.cloud
  region       = var.cc_region

  basic {}

  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.environment.id
  }
}

resource "confluent_kafka_cluster" "standard" {
  count        = var.confluent_cluster_type == "standard" ? 1 : 0
  display_name = var.cluster_name
  availability = var.availability
  cloud        = var.cloud
  region       = var.cc_region

  standard {}

  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.environment.id
  }
}
```

**Access the output at single place like**

```
locals {
  rest_endpoint       = var.confluent_cluster_type == "basic" ? confluent_kafka_cluster.basic[0].rest_endpoint : confluent_kafka_cluster.standard[0].rest_endpoint
  cluster_id          = var.confluent_cluster_type == "basic" ? confluent_kafka_cluster.basic[0].id : confluent_kafka_cluster.standard[0].id
  cluster_kind        = var.confluent_cluster_type == "basic" ? confluent_kafka_cluster.basic[0].kind : confluent_kafka_cluster.standard[0].kind
  cluster_api_version = var.confluent_cluster_type == "basic" ? confluent_kafka_cluster.basic[0].api_version : confluent_kafka_cluster.standard[0].api_version
}
```